# Dynamically Add a XML Layout to a TableRow Android

Tags: android, xml, tablerow

I want to add an xml element dynamically to the left of a `TableRow`.

Here is my xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="7dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dot" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

It looks like this: [image]

I want to obtain a timeline look. All of my elements are dynamically added table rows. And I need to add this xml view to the left of my table row. How can I do this?

EDIT:
  I tried adding it as a DrawableWithIntrinsicBounds to the left of the tablerow. But it looked like this: [image] . There was a gap between the shapes

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier (and more efficient) to set the "timeline look" as a background to your table row? A simple 9-patch would do the trick. Alternatively, it could be worth setting up your table row to handle the drawing of the timeline graphics itself (which would be more work, but also more flexible if i.e. you'd need to dynamically change its colours).

Comment: @MH. I haven't worked with 9-patch yet. Any example? And I will edit my question with the reason this solution with the background didn't work. Please check

Comment: i agree with @MH, he told truth,  truth and only truth

Comment: @pskink editedquestion with reason background didn't work

Comment: tried hierarchyviewer?  maybe the gaps are because your items are separated?

Comment: @GabiRotaru: Plenty of coverage on 9-patches on Google, but [read here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) about the basic idea. As far as the gap between the two rows goes: you probably have a margin or padding specific somewhere. If you can't figure it out from the layout files themselves, use the hierarchy viewer, or enable "Show Layout Bounds" under the Developer Options on your test device/emulator.

Comment: You should also show table row code. I had answered similar question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625912/draw-custom-line-between-two-elements-in-tablelayout-android/29627491#29627491), but it uses list view. Take a look if you like, you can also add items in list dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an xml file called: `timeline.xml` with the code you post above.
Then you have a layout for your table but you also have a layout for each item that you put in your table. It's probably called something like: `table_item.xml`

Then you can just include the `timeline.xml` into it and make sure it's to your left:

```
<include
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   layout="@layout/timeline.xml" />
```

Comment: All the elements of a TableRow are added dynamic. So I want to include this dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout file for the dynamic item.
Then make the dynamic view in a tablerow a ViewGroup and add inflated layout as a child of it in your code.